# relative path includetext in MS Word

Tags: ms-word, relative-path

I'm trying to use realtive paths in an MS Word file to streamline all links. Since relative paths are not possible as such in MS Word, I created a main path in the file's properties and I'm trying to embed this in all links. I have confirmed that this "property path" works, when I type this code link:

```
{ DOCPROPERTY "Path" /* MERGEFORMAT }
```

and update, it returns the path desired:

```
C:\\Users\\PATH
```

The problem is that when embedding this in a link, it does not seem to take the property path:

```
{ INCLUDETEXT "{ DOCPROPERTY Path }\\sum.xml" \n xmlns:ns1='schema.xsd' \x /ns1:aaaa/ns1:bbbb \* MERGEFORMAT }
```

which returns an error.

I also verified that the absolute path works well:

```
{ INCLUDETEXT "C:\\Users\\PATH\\sum.xml" \n xmlns:ns1='schema.xsd' \x /ns1:aaaa/ns1:bbbb \* MERGEFORMAT }
```

Does anybody know whether this is impossible or whether I am making a mistake?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: (1) what error are you seeing? (2) Are the { } surrounding "DOCPROPERTY Path" definitely the special field code brace pairs that you can insert using ctrl-F9 on Windows Word?

Comment: If they work with the absolute path, it may not be essential, but I would also consider quoting the namespace declarations and XPath expressions, e.g. { INCLUDETEXT "C:\\Users\\PATH\\sum.xml" \n "xmlns:ns1='schema.xsd'" \x "/ns1:aaaa/ns1:bbbb" \* MERGEFORMAT }. Probably just a typo, but as posted in your question, in your very first field code expression, you have { DOCPROPERTY "Path" /* MERGEFORMAT } when it should be { DOCPROPERTY "Path" \* MERGEFORMAT } (and in fact you could leave out the /* MERGEFORMAT anyway).

Answer (score 3):

You can indeed achieve relative paths with INCLUDETEXT fields. Here's how:

To make the INCLUDETEXT field look in the current folder, delete the path and replace it with a FILENAME field with the path switch, followed by /../ or \\..\\. To create the FILENAME field, see under Insert|Field [Word 2003 & earlier] or Insert|Quick Parts|Field [Word 2007 & later].

Your:

```
{INCLUDETEXT "C:\\Users\\PATH\\sum.xml" \n xmlns:ns1='schema.xsd' \x /ns1:aaaa/ns1:bbbb}
```

field code should thus become:

```
{INCLUDETEXT "{FILENAME \p}/../sum.xml" \n xmlns:ns1='schema.xsd' \x /ns1:aaaa/ns1:bbbb"}
```

or

```
{INCLUDETEXT "{FILENAME \p}\\..\\sum.xml" \n xmlns:ns1='schema.xsd' \x /ns1:aaaa/ns1:bbbb"}
```

**Note:** I've omitted the '* MERGEFORMAT' switch as it probably isn't needed.

How this works: The FILENAME p field extracts the current file's name and path. The following '\\..\\' or '/../' tells Word to ignore the filename and get just the path. Then all you need to do is to add the source file's name & extension - as per the above.

For more details, see: https://www.msofficeforums.com/word/38722-word-fields-relative-paths-external-files.html