# Relative path MS Word with INCLUDETEXT

Tags: cpu-word

I am trying to use INCLUDETEXT to automate a Table of Contents with number of pages from various other .docm files in folders below main folder.

I have trouble using relative paths in MS Word per: [relative path includetext in MS Word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59211635)

Here is my effort which results in an

> "Error! Not a valid filename":
> {INCLUDETEXT  "{FILENAME \P } \..\..\Div 22 Plumbing\SECTION 22 07 80.DOCM" Pages}

> Div 22... folder is one level the FILENAME path. Pages is a bookmark in the .docm file.

I tried like this too with same negative result:

```
{INCLUDETEXT  "{FILENAME \P } \\..\\Div 22 Plumbing\SECTION 22 07 80.DOCM" Pages}
```

I am able to get the contents of Pages into my TOC if I just use the INCLUDETEXT from an external file in the same folder, I just can't seem to get the contents from a file in a subfolder.

Answer (score 0):

in your example, you put this:

```
{INCLUDETEXT  "{FILENAME \P } \\..\\Div 22 Plumbing\SECTION 22 07 80.DOCM" Pages}
```

did you mean this:

```
{INCLUDETEXT  "{FILENAME \P } \\..\\Div 22 Plumbing\\SECTION 22 07 80.DOCM" Pages}
```